# Adding buffer to 1D coordinate

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot}

\psset{unit=0.1cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3.0, -25)(110, 24.0)

\psaxes[Ox=0,Dx=10,yAxis=false]{->}(-2.0,-20)(105,23)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The axis runs from `0..100`, as desired - but I would like for it to start at e.g. -2 or -3, such that there is a "buffer" before the axis starts. The ticks should be as they are now, i.e. at 0, 10, 20, .... All I want is a "buffer-axis" that starts at -2.

If I use `Ox=-2`, then the ticks run from -2, 8, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tell `pspicture` that the origin is at `(0,0)`:

```
\psaxes[Dx=10,yAxis=false]{->}(0,0)(-2.0,-20)(105,23)
```